# Mac surface scan tool

Tags: mac, hard-drive, repair

I've had an SDcard lose its partition table, so I want to run a surface scan of the sdcard to make sure it's physically okay. Can you suggest a disk surface scan tool that runs on the Mac? Free, preferably. Thanks.

Comment: IMO, with the price of SD cards being what they are, if you have any doubts of the integrity of this card, throw it away and buy a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of my favorite Mac developers released just the tool for your task.

It's called [stressdrive](https://github.com/rentzsch/stressdrive) and writes the entire drive with data and reads it back to ensure every bit was readable and matches what was written.